# How can I automatically publish a web api web service after a successful build?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the ASP.NET MVC Web API (VS 2010) to create REST-ful web services that do not have an associated web page. They are part of a suite of tools (including Windows Services, thick clients, and maybe later some web pages) that run simultaneously. So during debugging I want to automatically publish the web service to my local IIS after every build so it is always available.

The "Publish..." context menu does this, but I'd like it done automatically as a post-build event (or something). I don't want to have to clutter the solution with additional Web Deployment projects for this simple purpose. I also don't want to have to map virtual directories to my build tree since that is problematic when working with different branches.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to autopublish everytime you compile? That's absolutely insane. Don't do it. It will slow your development time enormously, you will have to drink more and more coffees every-time you hit Shift+F5 in order to compile, and also expose all the bugs you do in development to all clients immediately. Use IIS Express while developing and once you feel that you have something working go and  publish. Also define a web deployment project, otherwise how do you intend to deploy in production? With a post-compile event directly from Visual Studio?

Comment: Also, I don't think VS offers automatic publish (i could be wrong, just have never seen it). But there is the ability for a "one click publish". If you are interested, you can check out the "The one click deploy" section of [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103930/VS-2010-Deployment-Package-One-click-deploy-and-We).

Comment: Darin: publishing to localhost will not expose the code to any clients. The web services are only one piece of the total solution. I may eventually need a web deployment project, or we might deal with it differently when we come to release time. But for now I'd like to avoid it.